# Adding arbitrary extensions to URLs generated by Django

Tags: django, django-urls

Django has excellent URLConf and URL reverse mapping/matching. I'm looking for a tip/trick to add arbitrary extensions to URLs generated by Django. Sometimes it's nice to see extensions that suggest your brand.

Comment: Could you provide some examples?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking here. What sort of 'extensions'?

Comment: Say adding .html or .xyz to your URL. Example: http://site.com/view/this-is-slug.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's assume I want to publish some documents which are available in HTML, PDF, DOC, etc formats. The pattern in urlconf would look like this:

```
(r"^/docs/(?P<doc_slug>[\w-]+).(?P<ext>\w+)$", myapp.views.view_doc),
```

and the view:

```
def view_doc(request, doc_slug, ext):
    if ext == "html":
        #...
    elif ext == "pdf":
        #...
    else:
        return Http404("Document not available in this format")
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, but not really. But you gave me an idea how to do this.

Comment: imho better way: `(r"^/docs/(?P<doc_slug>[\w-]+).(?P<ext>[pdf|html|doc]+)$", myapp.views.view_doc),`

Comment: @cetver you're splitting knowledge of possible extensions between urlconf and view implementation.  OK when formats aren't going to change often, but I wouldn't do it myself